# Ubuntu 18.04 wired ethernet connection not working

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, webkit

I have a linux machine, running Ubuntu 18.04, and my wired connection is no longer working. (I can only connect with Ethernet - no wifi card), and I have checked the Ethernet cable on another device and it works fine, so I know the computer is the issue. I recently did an update where webkit was updated, and so I tried rolling all those updates back, but still no connection. From the network settings, it doesn't show any issue. Any advice on how to troubleshoot further?

Comment: Shutdown computer, remove cable, reboot and connect cable after.  Might be driver.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that, but it didn't change anything. The updates were also to grub-common. I have tried re-booting, and can reboot through UEFI, but still no internet connection. The 'Network' gui says "Connected 1000 Mb/s" but I can't access any URLs.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to select "Remove Connection Profile" in the Networking GUI.  Now everything works fine.